# gzip compression not working in Solr 5.1

Tags: solr, compression, jetty, gzip, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to apply gzip compression in Solr 5.1. I understand that Running Solr on Tomcat is no longer supported from Solr 5.0, so I've tried to implement it in Solr.

I've downloaded jetty-servlets-9.3.0.RC0.jar and placed it in my webapp\WEB-INF folder, and have added the following in webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>methods</param-name>
         <param-value>GET,POST</param-value>
         <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
         <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,application/xhtml+xml,application/javascript,image/svg+xml,application/json,application/xml; charset=UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, when I start Solr and check the browser, there's no gzip compression, and I only get the following at the Response Headers output:
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Is there anything which I configure wrongly or might have missed out? I'm also running zookeeper-3.4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a kosher version of Jetty that closely matches what is currently in Solr: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html

Extract that .zip to a location you will discard.
Copy out these files to your copy of jetty in Solr (located in path-to-solr/server/):

- `modules/gzip.mod`
- `etc/gzip.xml`

Modify `modules/gzip.mod`:

```
#
# GZIP module
# Applies GzipHandler to entire server
#

[depend]
server

[xml]
etc/jetty-gzip.xml

[ini-template]
## Minimum content length after which gzip is enabled
jetty.gzip.minGzipSize=2048

## Check whether a file with *.gz extension exists
jetty.gzip.checkGzExists=false

## Gzip compression level (-1 for default)
jetty.gzip.compressionLevel=-1

## User agents for which gzip is disabled
jetty.gzip.excludedUserAgent=.*MSIE.6\.0.*
```

Modify `etc/gzip.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Mixin the GZIP Handler                                          -->
<!-- This applies the GZIP Handler to the entire server              -->
<!-- If a GZIP handler is required for an individual context, then   -->
<!-- use a context XML (see test.xml example in distribution)        -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Call name="insertHandler">
        <Arg>
            <New id="GzipHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler">
                <Set name="minGzipSize">
                    <Property name="jetty.gzip.minGzipSize" deprecated="gzip.minGzipSize" default="2048"/>
                </Set>
                <Set name="checkGzExists">
                    <Property name="jetty.gzip.checkGzExists" deprecated="gzip.checkGzExists" default="false"/>
                </Set>
                <Set name="compressionLevel">
                    <Property name="jetty.gzip.compressionLevel" deprecated="gzip.compressionLevel" default="-1"/>
                </Set>
                <Set name="excludedAgentPatterns">
                    <Array type="String">
                        <Item>
                            <Property name="jetty.gzip.excludedUserAgent" deprecated="gzip.excludedUserAgent" default=".*MSIE.6\.0.*"/>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Set>
                <Set name="includedMethods">
                    <Array type="String">
                        <Item>GET</Item>
                        <Item>POST</Item>
                    </Array>
                </Set>

    <Set name="includedPaths"><Array type="String"><Item>/*</Item></Array></Set>

    <Set name="excludedPaths"><Array type="String"><Item>*.gz</Item></Array></Set>

    <Call name="addIncludedMimeTypes"><Arg><Array type="String">
        <Item>text/html</Item>
        <Item>text/plain</Item>
        <Item>text/xml</Item>
        <Item>application/xml</Item><!-- IMPORTANT - DO NOT FORGET THIS LINE -->
        <Item>application/xhtml+xml</Item>
        <Item>text/css</Item>
        <Item>application/javascript</Item>
        <Item>image/svg+xml</Item>
    </Array></Arg></Call>
                <!--
    <Call name="addExcludedMimeTypes"><Arg><Array type="String"><Item>some/type</Item></Array></Arg></Call>
    -->
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

Here's the part that should make you cringe a bit.
Modify `bin\solr.cmd`

```
...
set "SOLR_JETTY_CONFIG=--module=http,gzip"
...
set "SOLR_JETTY_CONFIG=--module=https,gzip"
...
```

Notice that `--module=http` was already there.  Just add `",gzip"` so it matches the lines above.
I would prefer finding a better way of specifying the gzip module to load, but I don't know how.  If you know how, please reply to this answer and tell me how because I hate modifying a script that comes with a product--it's a maintenance nightmare and, well, I think you get the picture.

After this, restart the solr server and gzip should now be enabled--at least for `&wt=xml`, which is sent back as `Content-Type: application/xml`.
You can add what you need to the `etc/gzip.xml` and restart the solr server for it to recognize your changes.

I tested with and without compression of 1000 documents.  For me, it was the difference between 3.8 MB and 637 KB.

Comment: NOTE: I used solr 6.1.0, so keep that in mind if you need to make some adjustments.  I know that the .war file went away somewhere about solr 5.4 or 5.5.